# Python MySQL CSV export to json strange encoding

Tags: python, mysql, json, csv, utf-8

I received a csv file exported from a MySQL database (I think the encoding is latin1 since the language is spanish). Unfortunately the encoding is wrong and I cannot process it at all. If I use file:

`$ file -I file.csv 
file.csv: text/plain; charset=unknown-8bit`

I have tried to read the file in python and convert it to utf-8 like:

`r.decode('latin-1').encode("utf-8")`

or using *mysql_latin1_codec*:

`r.decode('mysql_latin1').encode('UTF-8')`

I am trying to transform the data into json objects. The error comes when I save the file:

**'UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position'**

Do you know how can I convert it to normal utf-8 chars? Or how can I convert data to a valid json? Thanks!!

Comment: could you provide an example of what you are trying to decode, cause with just the error is not easy to reproduce the problem and find a possible solution...

Comment: sure, in the csv the fields appear like this: e.g. DIRECCI��N BARCELONA, v��lida hasta, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got really good results by using pandas dataframe from Continuum Analytics.

You coud do something like:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import *

con='Your database connection credentials user, password, host, database to use'
data=pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM YOUR TABLE',conn=con)
```

Then you could do:

```
data.to_csv('path_with_file_name')
```

or to convert to JSON:

```
data.to_json(orient='records')
```

or if you prefer to customize your json format see the documentation here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Comment: hi Beatriz, indeed, I used pandas to open the csv and deployed them to a json using force_ascii=True and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the codecs module?:

```
import codecs
....
codecs.EncodedFile(r, 'latin1').reader.read()
```

I remember having a similar issue a while back and the answer was something to do with how encoding was done prior to Python 3. Codecs seems to handle this problem relatively elegantly.

As coder mentioned in the question comments, it's difficult to pinpoint the problem without being able to reproduce it so I may be barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: I've ried that and other things also, no success :(. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably have two problems.  But let's back off...  We can't tell whether the text was imported incorrectly, exported incorrectly, or merely displayed in a goofy way.

First, I am going to discuss "importing"...

Do not try to alter the encoding.  Instead live with the encoding.  But first, figure out what the encoding is.  It could be latin1 or it could be utf8.  (Or any of lots of less likely charsets.)

Find out the hex for the incoming file.  In Python, the code is something like this for dumping hex (etc) for string `u`:

```
for i, c in enumerate(u):
    print i, '%04x' % ord(c), unicodedata.category(c),
    print unicodedata.name(c)
```

You can go [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#8_bit_encodings) to see a list of hex values for all the latin1 characters, together with the utf8 hex.  For example, `ó` is latin1 `F3` or utf8 `C2B3`.

Now, armed with knowing the encoding, tell MySQL that.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE ...
    ...
    CHARACTER SET utf8  -- or latin1
    ...;
```

Meanwhile, it does not matter what `CHARACTER SET ...` the *table* or *column* is defined to be; mysql will transcode if necessary.  All Spanish characters are available in latin1 and utf8.

Go to [*this Q&A*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) .

I suggested that you have two errors, one is the "black diamond" case mentioned there; there other is something else.  But...  Follow the "Best Practice" mentioned.

Back to you question of "exporting"...

Again, you need to check the hex of the output file.  Again it does not matter whether it is latin1 or utf8.  However...  If the hex is `C383C2B3` for simply `ó`, you have "double encoding".  If you have that, check to see that you have removed any manual conversion function calls, and simply told MySQL what's what.

Here are some more [*utf8+Python tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python) you might need.

If you need more help, follow the text step-by-step.  Show us the code used to move/convert it at each step, and show us the HEX at each step.

Comment: Hi Rick and thank you for your wonderful explanation. I am aware of your tips, but, unfortunately, I don't have access to MySQL. I am restricted to some csv files already exported wrong:(.

Comment: Can you use Python to discover the hex in the files?  Perhaps read as "binary", then look at the hex?  (I don't speak Python, so I can't help with specific code.)  Or maybe a hex-dump utility?

Comment: You mean something like this: \x89\xe3\xa2 ?

Comment: Yuck.  `\x89\xe3\xa2` is `‰ã¢` in latin1; incorrectly encoded to be utf8, `됥` in Korean (euckr), etc.  What _should_ it have been?

Comment: Hmmm... I see no way to get between `©` and that hex `89e3a3`.  Do you have an example of another string and hex?

Comment: Sure: M\xc3\x81LAGA for Málaga.

Comment: `C381` is utf8 encoding of `Á`; `C3A1` is the lower case version.  Was the actual text upper or lower case?

Comment: I get this kind of characters: ��

Comment: It probably means you were connecting as latin1.  See my link and look for Black Diamond.

Comment: What link are you referencing to?